# Description of the kernel of the tensor product of two linear maps

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $A$ be a commutative, unital ring and let $M_i$ and $N_i$ be $A$-modules ($i=1,2)$.

If $\alpha_1:M_1\to N_1$ and $\alpha_2:M_2\to N_2$ are $A$-linear, then we get a unique $A$-linear map 
$$\alpha_1\otimes\alpha_2 : M_1\otimes_A M_2\to N_1\otimes N_2$$
which sends
$$m_1\otimes m_2 \mapsto \alpha_1(m_1)\otimes\alpha_2(m_2)$$
for all $m_i \in M_i.$

---

*Question:* How much can we say about the kernel of this map?

---

*Thoughts so far:* It clear that if $m_1 \in \ker(\alpha_1),$ then $m_1\otimes y \in \ker(\alpha_1\otimes\alpha_2)$ for all $y \in M_2.$

Similarly, if $m_2 \in \ker(\alpha_2),$ then $x\otimes m_2 \in \ker(\alpha_1\otimes \alpha_2)$ for all $x \in M_1.$

This would lead me to guess that (perhaps under some extra conditions) we might have:

$$\ker(\alpha_1\otimes \alpha_2)\cong(\ker(\alpha_1)\otimes_A M_2)\oplus(M_1\otimes_A\ker(\alpha_2)).$$

*Gut feeling:* Since tensoring doesn't generally preserve injectivity, things might not be so clean...

I would be grateful if someone could tell me what results there are in this direction if any!

Many thanks :)

Comment: Your guts are right. The isomorphism isn't always true (at least not via the canonical map). See Remark 19 (a) in http://web.mit.edu/~darij/www/algebra/tensorext.pdf .

Comment: Ah okay, but if they are both surjective, then it works out. That's good because both my maps are sujrective! :) Thank you for the link!

Comment: Well, "it works out" is relative, because the two tensor products on the right hand side in your claim aren't the ones in my Theorem 18. See Remark 9 (b) (although no counterexample this time; but I think it shouldn't be hard to find one).

Comment: Ah yes :) Nice document btw!

Comment: The link I posted above should be replaced by http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/tensorext.pdf .